# LMS Security Proof Paper

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, hash-signature

Is there any LMS security proof besides the [one](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/553) mentioned in [RFC 8554](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8554)? Does LMS actually have a paper which describes a proof?

Comment: Did you try looking for it on Cryptology eprint Archive by keyword search itself?

Comment: By a single keyword search: I could find somewhat relevant reports like 2021/041, 2017/349 and 2020/470

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any LMS security proof besides the one mentioned in RFC 8554?

The RFC actually references several articles. A relevant one is Jonathan Katz's [*Analysis of a Proposed Hash-Based Signature Standard*](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Ejkatz/papers/HashBasedSigs-SSR16.pdf), in [proceedings of SSR 2016](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-49100-4_12).

But the standard proposal has then changed and it's necessary to look at Scott Fluhrer's [*Further Analysis of a Proposed Hash-Based Signature Standard*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/553.pdf), [eprint 2017/553](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/553), the main reference in the RFC.

Update: Another reference is Edward Eaton's [*Leighton-Micali Hash-Based Signatures in the Quantum Random-Oracle Model*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/607.pdf), in [proceedings of SAC 2017](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-72565-9_13). This and the previous document are listed as references in [NIST SP800-208](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.SP.800-208), which endorses LMS as in RFC 8554.

From an intellectual property standpoint, there is Frank T. Leighton and Silvio Micali's [*Large provably fast and secure digital signature schemes based on secure hash functions*](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/5f/82/ec/ba345135c014d9/US5432852.pdf), [US patent 5,432,852](https://image-ppubs.uspto.gov/dirsearch-public/print/downloadPdf/5432852), filed 1993, published 1995, expired 2013.

Disclaimer: I have read none of these.

Comment: so the only proof is in a non-peer reviewed preprint?

Comment: @Kris: made an update with an additional reference, which happens to be peer-reviewed; and with NIST SP800-208, which endorses LMS as in RFC 8554.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the works that fgrieu cited, there is also [Edward Eaton's paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/607.pdf) analyzing LMS in the Quantum Oracle model.